# Python & Pandas: apply scoring function to df new column not working

Tags: python, pandas, apply, scoring

I want to create a score based on the value of several columns in the dataframe. I created the following snippet but the function does not apply as it return only 0 values...

```
def momentum_score (row): 
   
    if ((row['rsi_1'] < 30) & (row['rsi_2'] > 30) & (row['rsi_3'] > 30)):
        val = 1  
    if ((row['rsi_1'] < 30) & (row['rsi_2'] < 30) & (row['rsi_3'] > 30)):
        val = 2 
    if ((row['rsi_1'] < 30) & (row['rsi_2'] < 30) & (row['rsi_3'] < 30)):
        val = 3
    else:
        val=0
    return val
    
dfw['mom'] = dfw.apply(momentum_score, axis=1)
dfw
```

Please see the picture to have a look at my dataframe [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtOUm.png)

Comment: I would suggest to use direct boolean indexing and then assigning to the selected rows, instead of running apply.

Comment: Have you considered using a lambda function? Something like:

      dfw['mom'] = dfw.apply(lambda r: momentum_score(r), axis=1)

Comment: @AlessandroTogni `.apply` already takes a function as a first argument. Why would you want to wrap that in a `lambda function`? It achieves nothing, just extra overhead.

Comment: Yeah, i wrote something senseless, you're right. 
I was thinking about unwrap the momentum_score function to one or plus lambdas, maybe one for each if condition. Still not the best solution.
Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with apply but it's slower than a vectorized solution.
The problem is the use of the if-elif-els statement.

```py
def momentum_score (row): 
    if ((row['rsi_1'] < 30) & (row['rsi_2'] > 30) & (row['rsi_3'] > 30)):
        val = 1  
    elif ((row['rsi_1'] < 30) & (row['rsi_2'] < 30) & (row['rsi_3'] > 30)):
        val = 2 
    elif ((row['rsi_1'] < 30) & (row['rsi_2'] < 30) & (row['rsi_3'] < 30)):
        val = 3
    else:
        val=0
    return val
    
dfw['mom'] = dfw.apply(momentum_score, axis=1)
dfw
```

Comment: You may want to point out that the use of an if-elif-elif-else chain is the solution to the actual problem the OP has. Which doesn't really have to do anything to do with Pandas and dataframes, but just with the logic behind if/else branches.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

```
rsi1 = dfw['rsi_1']
rsi2 = dfw['rsi_2']
rsi3 = dfw['rsi_3']

conds =\
[(rsi1 < 30) & (rsi2 > 30) & (rsi3 > 30), 
 (rsi1 < 30) & (rsi2 < 30) & (rsi3 > 30),
 (rsi1 < 30) & (rsi2 < 30) & (rsi3 < 30)]
choices = [1, 2, 3]
#choices = list(range(1, len(conds)+1))

df['mom'] = np.select(conds, choices, default=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead (untested, but I think this is what you want):

```
dfw.loc['mom'] = 0  # default value

rsi1 = dfw['rsi_1']
rsi2 = dfw['rsi_2']
rsi3 = dfw['rsi_3']
dfw.loc[(rsi1 < 30) & (rsi2 > 30) & (rsi3 > 30), 'mom'] = 1
dfw.loc[(rsi1 < 30) & (rsi2 < 30) & (rsi3 > 30), 'mom'] = 2
dfw.loc[(rsi1 < 30) & (rsi2 < 30) & (rsi3 < 30), 'mom'] = 3
```